# У слова "наверное" есть два противоположных значения?

Tags: пунктуация, смысл

Я правильно понимаю, исходя из статьи на [грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_426), что если не выделять "наверное" запятыми, то это слово принимает противоположное значение и только массовое незнание позволяет избегать неудобных ситуаций?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правильно понимаете: слово *наверное* может иметь значение *наверняка*, в этом случае оно не выделяется запятыми.